# linq to sql, inner join vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, inner-join

I have a simple question on inner join using linq to sql - how do I display all fields from both tables, or only certain fields from both tables? Once I've mastered this I'll start looking at lambda coding. The code below is from 101 linq to sql samples.

```
Dim ordCount = From cust In db.Customers
                       Group Join ord In db.Orders On cust.CustomerID Equals ord.CustomerID
                       Into orders = Group
                       Select cust.Phone, ord.shipcity      'ord.shipcity gives an error
```

how do you select all fields from both tables?

```
Dim ordCount = From cust In db.Customers
                           Group Join ord In db.Orders On cust.CustomerID Equals ord.CustomerID
                           Into orders = Group
                           Select orders
```

Comment: `Group Join` is equivalent to outer join. `orders` is a collection.

Comment: Thanks Gert, I'm not sure what to do with your reply. Can you post some code which will return all fields from both tables? and then code to select only certain fields?

Comment: Got it, thanks. should have been using a ``join`` and not a ``group join``.